# What are the recommended telemetry services for mobile platforms using Xamarin

Tags: telemetry

I have created a Xamarin Forms application.

My requirements are the following:

- send usage statistics to a telemetry service
- send crash reports to a telemetry service

The .Net platform is a Microsoft territory and they have their own telemetry service: [Application Insights](https://www.visualstudio.com/application-insights/).

I searched but I couldn't find any way to use it in my project, it seems it does not support Xamarin projects.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information then fix your question. In particular: List all of your requirements. Do not mention any particular product except the one you can NOT use and in such case explicitly tell why it does not fit your requirements. When you are done, please comment and I will reopen. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I modified the initial post.